# Having problem in js evenlistener click on touch screen

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

I am new to JavaScript, and I am encountering an issue with the following code. As you can see, I am trying to execute a function when a user clicks a button, and the email should be copied. The code works fine on laptop devices, but on touch screens, it's not functioning. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, please reply. Thank you!

```
let copy = document.querySelector(".copy");

const copied = () =>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    copy.innerHTML = "<i class='bx bx-copy'></i> Copy email";
    copy.classList.remove("copied");
  }, "1500");
}

const copyfnc = () =>{
  navigator.clipboard.writeText("email@gmail.com");
  copy.classList.add("copied")
  copy.innerHTML = "<i class='bx bx-check' ></i> email copied"
  copied();
}


copy.addEventListener("click", () =>{
  copyfnc();
})
copy.addEventListener("touchstart", () =>{
  copyfnc();
})
```

expexting somone can fix it or give me some suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can use `touchend` instead of `touchstart` and also, it's better to prevent the default behavior of the touch event to ensure it works as expected.

```
copy.addEventListener("touchend", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default touch behavior
  copyfnc();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

navigator.clipboard is still not supported on some browsers (like mine).
You could try to use the deprecated old methode with document.execCommand('copy')

```
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  if (navigator.clipboard) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  }
  else {
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = text;

    // Avoid scrolling to bottom
    textArea.style.top = "0";
    textArea.style.left = "0";
    textArea.style.position = "fixed";

    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.focus();
    textArea.select();

    try {
      document.execCommand('copy');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Fallback: Oops, unable to copy', err);
    }

    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
  }
}
```